# How to backup and restore sessions on Fiddler startup and shutdown?

Tags: automation, fiddler

What I want is backup all sessions at `Fiddler` shutdown and when I turn it on again it needs to load that sessions again.

I managed to change the `FiddlerScript` by creating a `save` action and dump all sessions with this:

```
case "save":
    FiddlerObject.UI.actSelectAll();
    FiddlerObject.UI.actSaveSessionsToZip(CONFIG.GetPath("Captures") + "saved.saz");
    FiddlerObject.StatusText = "Saved in " + CONFIG.GetPath("Captures") + "saved.saz";
break;
```

It works fine and all currently loaded sessions are saved.

I tried to create a action to restore them but it does nothing (I loaded the session but don't know how to get back in the grid):

```
case "restore":
    //I don't know what I need to do with this
    Utilities.ReadSessionArchive(CONFIG.GetPath("Captures") + "saved.saz", true);
break;
```

After that I want to do something similar do execute them with `ExecAction` at startup and shutdown but this is another part of my puzzle.

**TL;DR**

How to restore a previously saved dump using `FiddlerScript` on startup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rules > Customize Rules.

Update the **OnBoot** and **OnShutdown** functions thusly:

```
static function OnBoot() {
    FiddlerApplication.UI.actLoadSessionArchive("_stored.saz");
}

static function OnShutdown() {
    FiddlerApplication.UI.actSelectAll();
    var sFilename = (CONFIG.GetPath("Captures") + "_stored.saz");
    FiddlerApplication.UI.actSaveSessionsToZip(sFilename);
}
```